# Checking the value in the array javascript

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I am doing some API testing.

I am trying to check the name from the API response.

The API response is presenting data in an array.

I am checking if the name activeadmin exists however I am getting back an error The Repository activeadmin exists | AssertionError: expected 'pineapple' to deeply equal 'activeadmin'

I dont understand why its checking the second name value in the array rather then the first one?

Here is my code

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json()

pm.test('The Repository activeadmin exists', () => {
    _.each(jsonData, (item) => {
        pm.expect(item.name).to.eql('activeadmin')
    })
})
```

I have tried using item[0].name but this comes back with error name is undefined

Below is the API Response

```
   [
{
"id": 2847287348,
"node_id": "sdhjaskdhkjasdhjashd",
"name": "activeadmin",
"full_name": "apple/activeadmin",
"private": false
   },
 {
"id": 2847287348,
"node_id": "sdhjaskdhkjasdhjashd",
"name": "pineapple",
"full_name": "apple/activeadmin",
"private": false
 },
 {
"id": 2847287348,
"node_id": "sdhjaskdhkjasdhjashd",
"name": "orange",
"full_name": "apple/activeadmin",
"private": false
 } ]
```

Comment: Try it with `item[0].name` instead of `item(0).name`.

Comment: Sorry I meant I have tried [0] and it doesn't work

Comment: @Sascha - I tried that and I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: This looks like `item[0]` is undefined.

Comment: @Sascha - Yes exactly, how do I fix this

Comment: Are you sure jsonData matches the API response you're showing? Can you debug/output jsonData to confirm?

Answer (score 1):

The code works correct. It's iterating through every element of the response.
You are using _.each where I guess it takes the 0, the 1, etc.

So it crashes when it goes into the second element which clearly doesn't have your
specified name.

You should access your jsonData[0] element's name.

You can implement the test functionality in a different function an apply it on
jsonData[0].

If this doesn't work for you, provide us with information about the
test function and the pm object.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working as expected. Problem is that whenever you call `pm.expect` it will check if the name is `'activeadmin'`. Since you have an array of values it will fail the test soon as it fails the first time. To fix this I would suggest the following code:

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json()

pm.test('The Repository activeadmin exists', () => {
    let activeAdminExists = false
    _.each(jsonData, (item) => {
        if(item.name == 'activeadmin'){
             activeAdminExists = true
        }
    });
    pm.expect(activeAdminExists ).to.eql(true)
})
```